# How does Express SessionParser exactly store data on the client side?

Tags: node.js, session, express

In my current setup SessionParser is set to work along with CookieParser, but I'm not sure how can I access cookie data set in this manner:

```
request.session.myKey = "myValue"
```

from the client's browser?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, you are setting a session variable in your code below:

```
request.session.myKey = "myValue"
```

Session variables are stored on the server either in-memory, redis, mongo or anywhere.  Session variables are not accessible on the client unless you implement some workarounds.

## Workaround - 1

Create a hidden variable in your form and set the session variable(s) and value(s) as hidden form elements when rendering the response.

## Workaround - 2

Initiate an ajax request and return a json result which contains the session variable(s) and value(s).

Cookie variables are stored on the client browser and available in the DOM as document.cookie in name=value pairs format e.g. myKey1=myValue1;myKey2=myValue2.  You can use raw JavaScript to access these values but you will need to split the the content of document.cookie and search for the cookie's name.  Use jQuery if you have jQuery on the client as it will save you from re-inventing the wheel.

However, I would imagine you really need to first know how cookies & sessions are combined to provide state for the http protocol and the security implications of using cookies.

I hope I have pointed you in the right direction to finding a solution.

SO1

Comment: Yes, thanks for the insight about differences in session and cookie.  Actually, what I ended up doing is using localStorage since I don't need the data to be transferred to server on each request.